# How to make a video stop when a user clicks away from it?

Tags: javascript, html, css, video, youtube

I have two divs that are hidden and when you click on one of the two buttons, I change that display none to display block and make the video available to play.

```
  .row.hidden.overflowHidden(data-park="hollywood")
        .col2-3.title(style="padding:0px;")
          div(style="padding:27px;")
            h3 Get the star treatment!
            h2 Universal Studios Hollywood&trade;
          //- .videoContainer.mobilehide
          //-   iframe( class="videoClass mobilehide" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/xRUDijZgyHc?rel=0', frameborder='0', allowfullscreen='')
          div
            iframe( height="400" width="100%" src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/xRUDijZgyHc?rel=0', frameborder='0', allowfullscreen='')
        .details.col1-3
          div
            h4 You could win a 3-night trip for four.
            p Prize includes:
            ul
              li Round-trip airfare to Los Angeles, California 
              li Ground transportation between the airport and hotel in Los Angeles
              li General Admission tickets for four to Universal Studios Hollywood&trade; theme park
              li Hotel accommodations
```

this is one of the videos examples, and when I click the other link it turns that block back to display hidden and the next video to display block. But the one that switches to display hidden continues to play in the back.

Is there any way to stop that video when the user clicks on the next video and switches that video back to display hidden?

Comment: Would you be able to post correctly formatted code?

Answer (score 1):

To stop the playing video, you can use the `pause()` method on it. And if you want to rewind it to the beginning too, use the `currentTime` property.

Example:

```
var video = document.getElementById("myVideoPlayer");
video.pause();
video.currentTime = 0;
```

Answer (score 1):

Since your video is an embedded YouTube video, you can take advantage of YouTube's [iframe javascript API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/iframe_api_reference)...

Append ?enablejsapi=1 to your embed link:

```
src='https://www.youtube.com/embed/xRUDijZgyHc?rel=0&enablejsapi=1'
```

Then, keep track of the video element that is initially clicked on in a variable from within a click [event handler](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/Events/Event_handlers):

`// You might consider giving your iframe elements a specific ID or class for more precise selection
var player = document.getElementsByTagName("div iframe")[0];`

When the next video is clicked on, call:

```
player.pauseVideo();
```

Comment: Answering questions that have no jQuery tag with a jQuery code is not a good idea. Some will downvote you for that.

Comment: Thanks for the call out! I'll pay more attention to the tags next time.

Comment: Don't wait till the next time, you can edit your answer now and provide a vanilla JavaScript answer. It's simply `yourHiddenVideoVariable.pause()`. If you like, you can also keep the jQuery code, but mention that it is for jQuery. Welcome to SO and thank you for the contribution.

Comment: Thanks, Racil! I updated my answer to something that is more relevant and hopefully helpful.